# How to make sure all the text stay on top of the page

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, books

This might seem a bit of a weird question, but when I have sections in a book along with images, the text always seems to spread out throughout the page. Putting `\vfill` at then end of the page does the trick, but I don't want to have to do that repeatedly.

I can't seem to make a working example and I don't want to copy the code directly from my book for privacy reasons. But if anyone else has had this problem, it would be a great help to figure out a way to have some command which automatically ends every page with `\vfill`, as that fixes my spacing problem in books.

EDIT. Actually, here's one I don't mind sharing:[image]. This is one case where the spacing becomes too spread out. IF I put `\vfill` at the bottom, it improves the appearance. But I prefer to always have the code at the top of the page, with the spacing I provided it in my code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It might be helpful to include a MWE here so others can have more detailed information about this question.

Comment: @Karlo I tried making one on the side with lipsum, but for some reason it didn't create the spacing problem I'm getting. So, I'm not sure how to provide one. I know it will help, but I'm not sure what to do... I usually do if I can though...

Comment: Try with the `\raggedbottom` directive in your preamble.

Comment: @Bernard That seems to have done the trick! Thanks!

Comment: However, be aware pages will not necessarily end at exactly the same vertical position on the sheet (the default is `\flushbottom`).

Comment: @OsamaKawish A good way to provide an MWE is to copy your file and try to remove as much code as possible, while the problem is still there after compiling.

Comment: If \vfill but not \vfil works, I'll bet that you've got something like \parskip=0pt plus 1fil somewhere.